This warning suggests that `videojs.extend` is being used in `@brightcove/player-loader` or one of its dependencies
This warning suggests that videojs.extend is being used in @brightcove/player-loader or one of its dependencies, which is deprecated and will be removed in Video.js 8.0.0. Please provide guidance on how to resolve this warning or update the package to avoid using the deprecated method.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask


"Please provide guidance on how to resolve this warning ..."

You can't if you don't own @brightcove/player-loader, because it'd require to change the code inside that package. If you own it, change the code so that you do not use the .extend() method.
If you do not own @brightcove/player-loader:
Update the package to a newer version and see if the issue is fixed. If not: Try to find another package that provides the same functionality.


" ... or update the package to avoid using the deprecated method"

If there is an update that already fixes the issue, then you should simply install the new package/update the package according to the documentation of your package manager.

i have already update package but not work .
